# Unable to sort inner entities through jpql query in java springboot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Below is jpql query from a repository in my springboot project:

```
public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<TaskEntity, UUID> {  

@Query("SELECT DISTINCT t FROM TaskEntity t JOIN t.processes p JOIN p.agents a WHERE a.id = :agentId ORDER BY p.iat DESC")
Set<TaskEntity> findTasksByAgentId(UUID agentId); 

}
```

The desired output is list of tasks containing processes which have given agent id. I am getting this output however I also want processes to be sorted by iat (created time).
However processes are not getting sorted by this query. Note that processes is an inner entity of task, so `ORDER BY p.iat DESC` part of the query is not working.

I tried another query as well:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT t FROM TaskEntity t JOIN t.processes p JOIN p.agents a WHERE a.id = :agentId GROUP BY t.id ORDER BY MAX(p.iat) DESC")
Set<TaskEntity> findTasksByAgentId(UUID agentId);
```

but output is not sorted.

Below is my Task Entity for reference :

```
public class TaskEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @Enumerated
    private StatusEnum status;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "task", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<ProcessEntity> processes;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "task_customer",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    )
    private Set<CustomerEntity> customers;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "task_agent",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "agent_id")
    )
    private Set<AgentEntity> agents;

    private Date iat;
    private Date uat;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        iat = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        uat = new Date();
    }


}
```